# How to add margin on AlertControl Dexpress in c#

Tags: c#, devexpress

How can i programmatically add margin on alertcontrol form on showing. iv'e tried this event BeforeFormShow but seems nothing change.

Here's what i did.

```
private void alertControl1_BeforeFormShow(object sender,
        DevExpress.XtraBars.Alerter.AlertFormEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AlertForm.Location = new Point(500, 500);
        e.AlertForm.OpacityLevel = 1;

    }
```

PS: FormLocation: TopRight

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear the exact margins you mean, but to control the AlertForm's location you should use the [AlertFormEventArgs.Location](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsAlerterAlertControl_BeforeFormShowtopic) property that allows the alert-window's location to be manually specified.
So, just change your code as follows:

```
void alertControl1_BeforeFormShow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.Alerter.AlertFormEventArgs e) {
    e.Location = new Point(500, 500);
}
```